# MySQL: Error when insert and update: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, insert, foreign-keys

I've been reading some questions with the same problem I have but have not found the solution

**Database Estructure**

```
CREATE TABLE material (
  cve_mat varchar(12),
  type_mat varchar(20),
  author_mat varchar(40),
  status varchar(2),
  primary key(cve_mat)   
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE users (
  cve_user varchar(8),
  name_user varchar(25),
  lastn_user varchar(25),
  email_user varchar(25),
  primary key(cve_user)
)ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE material_user (
  cve_mat varchar(8),
  cve_user varchar(8),
  start_mat date,
  end_mat date,
  foreign key(cve_mat) references material(cve_mat)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  foreign key(cve_user) references users(cve_user)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

**And when execute these instructions:**

```
......
$query = "INSERT INTO material_user VALUES ('$cvemat','$ncontrol',NOW(),DATE_ADD(current_date, interval '$days' day))";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if ($result) {
$query = "UPDATE material SET status = 'YES' WHERE material.cve_mat = '$cvemat'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if ($result){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
} else {
return false;
}
```

**And display this error:**

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`biblioteca/material_prestamo`, CONSTRAINT `material_prestamo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cve_mat`) REFERENCES `material` (`cve_mat`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: There are two statements, at which do you see the mentioned error?

Comment: According to error, is for statement Insert!

Comment: Have you made sure that `$cvemat` exists in `material` table? Also, the data types don't match in length between `material_user.cve_mat` and `material.cve_mat`

Comment: $cvemat is a variable that contains a value for identify material!.. simple variable

Comment: yes! Is incorrect, the data types don't match.. now the error that display es this "NULL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the column types for the foreign key should match the referencing tables:

**material_user**

```
cve_mat varchar(8),
```

**material**

```
cve_mat varchar(12),
```

Those two column types should be equal.

Before your insert statement you can perform some debugging:

```
SELECT * FROM material WHERE cve_mat='$cvemat'
```

If all seems okay, you can run this to find out more details:

```
SHOW INNODB STATUS;
```

Comment: I have matched size of datatype to eight, but now display this error "NULL" (I use firebug)

Comment: @SoldierCorp You haven't explained how your code hooks up to anything that can be debugged using Firebug

Comment: I dont explain but the errors whith or without firebug are the same in this problem!... but yes, Im use firebug.

Comment: @SoldierCorp well, something changed between the first error and the next; you just have to determine what that is then.

Comment: Yes, when matched size of datatype, now display "NULL" only NULL and no anymore

Comment: @SoldierCorp sorry to says this, but you're going to have to find out why it displays `NULL` :)

Comment: @SoldierCorp I'm glad you were able to find it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have foreign key constrain so you need to execute your second query first then your fisrt query second. It may be help you

```
$query = "UPDATE material SET status = 'YES' WHERE material.cve_mat = '$cvemat'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if ($result) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO material_user VALUES  ('$cvemat','$ncontrol',NOW(),DATE_ADD(current_date, interval '$days' day))";
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```